# What can I do to get the Pi4J library to work with Java?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, pi4j

I am trying to get the Pi4J library to work on my Raspberry Pi 4. I just wrote a simple blink program. It is not toggling the pin as it should be.

Here is the simple program. I have compiled it, and it compiles fine and runs showing the state of the pin, logically. However, the pin is not going high when hooked up to a multimeter.

I am wondering if there is some system setting that is blocking the control of the GPIO pins from this library.

A little bit of info ... I am running Raspberry Pi OS full version. I am fully upgraded and updated. I am using Java 11. And I downloaded the latest Pi4J library as of last week.

```
    public class GPIOTest { 
      public static void main (String[] args) {
        Context pi4j = Pi4J.newAutoContext();
    
        DigitalOutput dirLeft = pi4j.dout().create(14);
    
        System.out.println(pi4j.getClass().toString());
        System.out.println(dirLeft.getClass().toString());
    
        while (true){
          System.out.println("Setting pin low.");
        
          dirLeft.low();
        
          System.out.println(dirLeft.state());
        
          try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Do nothing.
          } 
        
          System.out.println("Setting pin high.");
        
          dirLeft.high();
                    
          System.out.println(dirLeft.state());

          try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Do nothing.
          } 
        }
      }
    }
```

[image: Simple blink wiring]

Comment: Add a photo showing the (wrong) connections you have made.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the issue. I am not using Pi4J.

I wrote a simple Python script that takes care of the GPIO behavior of the system that I designed and called the script from Java. (I was not about to rewrite the rest of the system in Python, that would have just been a waste of time.)

If anyone has a solution to the question beyond this, please share. I am still willing to learn more.